# Существует ли способ скрывать/показывать колонки ListView через Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

Существует `ListView` с колонками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли возможность скрывать колонки при помощи биндинга? Например, если бы у `GridViewColumn` было свойство `Visibility`, то можно было бы к нему привязаться.

Обратил внимание, что используют вариант с заданием ширины колонки значением 0. Но предполагаю, что можно и по другому как-то

Comment: [How to Hide WPF ListView Columns in MVVM](http://dotnetpattern.com/how-to-hide-wpf-listview-columns-in-mvvm)

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за ответ! Проверю такой подход

Comment: @tym32167 можно проще `Width = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать с помощью `IValueConverter` и заданием нулевой `Width`.

Я использовал шаблон MVVM для реализации примера и вот такой вспомогательный класс для оповещения интерфейса об изменениях в свойствах.

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**Класс данных**

```csharp
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _ageVisible = true;

    public bool AgeVisible
    {
        get => _ageVisible;
        set
        {
            _ageVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get => _persons;
        set
        {
            _persons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person {Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "john@doe-family.com"},
            new Person {Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "jane@doe-family.com"},
            new Person {Name = "Asmmy Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "sammy.doe@gmail.com"},
        };
    }
}
```

**Конвертер**

```csharp
public class GridViewWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => value is bool v && v ? null : (object)0;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => null;
}
```

**View**

```csharp
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="600" Height="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:GridViewWidthConverter x:Key="GridViewWidthConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Content="Show Age" IsChecked="{Binding AgeVisible}" Margin="5"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" Width="{Binding AgeVisible, Converter={StaticResource GridViewWidthConverter}}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Тоже реализовывал через установку ширины (подсмотрел). Думаю, что в итоге оставлю такой вариант