# Как добавлять значения в разные колонки ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть 3 текст бокса (TB1, TB2, TB3) как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки данные этих текст боксов записывались в колонки ListView, причём TB1 в первую колонку, TB2 во-вторую и т.д? Я нуб в c# и wpf. Гуглил это вопрос, но что то у меня не работает ничего. Помогите.

Comment: Забудьте про такое понятие, как "Колонки", работайте с данными, а не с контролами. Данными в `ListView` являются простые классы, находящиеся в коллекции, которая задана как `ItemsSource`. `ListBox` - это тоже коллекция неких классов, либо простых `string` и других "базовых" типов. Вот у вас и сводится все к тому, чтобы получить выделенный сейчас объект из `ListBox`'ов (делается это при помощи привязки `SelectedItem`) и добавления нового класса (или редактирование выделенного) в коллекцию, которая привязана к `ListView`.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Но спасибо!

Comment: Зачем вы вообще упомянули в своём комментарии ListBox? Он здесь причём?

Comment: Опять же, повторюсь, я впервые учу какие либо языки программирования. У меня нет представления каким образом мне выделить отдельный текст бокс и вставить в нужное мне место

Comment: Простите, что-то прочитал эти сокращения по-своему `TB1, TB2, TB3`. Суть это не меняет, привязывайте к свойству и добавляйте в привязанную коллекцию новый класс. `каким образом мне выделить отдельный текст` - привязки (Binding), любая документация вам скажет как это сделать, всего лишь `<TextBox Text="{Binding НужноеСвойство}"/>`.

Comment: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1179702/373567), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116136/373567), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1109976/373567), [четыре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093568/373567) - это я только по своим собственным ответам поискал. Представляете, сколько их всего здесь, ответов на ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой пример с использованием MVVM для начинающих.

Суть WPF в том, что он легко позволяет делать приложения на более высоком уровне, чем WinForms. Например, не требуется залезать в контролы и их изменять, достаточно сказать контролу, где брать данные - сделать привязку `Binding`. Для того чтобы `Binding` смог реагировать на изменения свойств в коде, требуется реализация интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChnaged`.

Вот она

```cs
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Чтобы обслужить `ListView` и 3 текстбокса, в этом примере потребуется 4 свойства, одна коллекция и 3 строки. Так как в каждой строке `ListView` будет по 3 строки, создадим класс, представляющий данные для строки `ListView`.

```cs
public class MyItem
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Second { get; set; }
    public string Third { get; set; }
}
```

Еще будет кнопка, которая добавляет данные из текстбоксов как строчку в `ListView`. В MVVM очень неудобно использовать обработчики событий для работы с данными, как минимум потому что придется писать много лишнего кода. Поэтому вместо обработчика события `Click` для кнопки я буду использовать специально предназначенные для этого команды.

Чтобы удобно использовать команды, требуется вот такая реализация интерфейса `ICommand`.

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Далее, свойства не принято создавать в классе окна `MainWindow`, так как он предназначен только для работы с контролами, например для изменения поведения контролов, а мы будем работать с данными. В MVVM класс, в котором лежат данные, для того чтобы интерфейс (**View**, XAML) их забирал оттуда, называется **View Model**. Здесь и будет жить коллекция, которая хранит данные. А еще строки для самих текстбоксов.

По сути, вот весь код приложения

```cs
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _items;
    private ICommand _addCommand;
    private string _first, _second, _third;

    // с ObservableCollection можно работать как с List, разница лишь в том,
    // что она сообщает контролу, привязанному к ней о том, что произошли
    // изменения в составе коллекции. Вы добавляете сюда элемент, и он тут же появляется в интерфейсе.
    // С удалением, перемещением и т.д. - то же самое.
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items 
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // сообщает привязке, если вы создали новую коллекцию
        }
    }

    public string First // Сюда смотрит первый текстбокс
    {
        get => _first;
        set
        {
            _first = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // позволяет присваивать сюда текст с отображением изменений в интерфейсе
        }
    }

    public string Second
    {
        get => _second;
        set
        {
            _second = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Third
    {
        get => _third;
        set
        {
            _third = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand => _addCommand ?? (_addCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        // Ничего необычного.
        Items.Add(new MyItem { First = First, Second = Second, Third = Third });
        First = Second = Third = "";
        // После добавления очищаю текстбоксы, точнее свойства, а текстбоксы очищаются сами
    }, // логическое выражение, включает и отключает кнопку - CanExecute команды 
    parameter => First?.Length > 0 || Second?.Length > 0 || Third?.Length > 0));

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
    }
}
```

И последнее - View, то есть интерфейс

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="800" Height="500">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/><!-- создает ViewModel -->
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Первый" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBox Width="100" Margin="5" Text="{Binding First, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Второй" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBox Width="100" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Second, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Третий" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBox Width="100" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Third, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Button Content="Добавить" Margin="5" Padding="5,0" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Первый" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding First}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Второй" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Second}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Третий" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Third}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Вот и все - пишете в текстбоксах текст, жмете кнопку, информация добавляется в `ListView`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Само собой на полноценное приложение этот пример мало похож, но он явно демонстрирует, что такое MVVM. А это отдельная работа с интерфейсом и данными. Писать код в `MainWindow` классе теперь не нужно, от него больше нет зависимости. И выглядит он у меня вот так:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

На первый взгляд может показаться, что много всяких непонятных вспомогательных штук (не проще ли по старинке?), но эти штуки надо добавить в проект всего один раз, а жизнь они облегчать будут в течение всего дальнейшего развития этого проекта. К тому же освоив это один раз далее оно будет как родное, простое и понятное. MVVM - суперпопулярный шаблон проектирования для WPF, нагуглить можно очень много всего на эту тему, но я не буду вставлять сюда ссылки на материалы.