# Как задать свойство для элемента Material Design WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Мне нужно, чтобы из кода c# создавались элементы в xaml. Единственный способ, который я знаю - это создание экземпляров объекта и помещение его в контент другого. Например:

```
Card card = new Card()
{
    Height = 450,
    Background = Brushes.LightGray,
    UniformCornerRadius = 10,
};
listView.Items.Add(card);
```

Я использую инструмент Material Design in XAML, в котором есть зависимые свойства для элементов. В XAML это выглядит следующим образом:

```
<materialDesign:Card Height="450" Background="LightGray" UniformCornerRadius="10" materialDesign:ElevationAssist.Elevation="Dp0">
```

**Вопрос: Как мне задать свойство ElevationAssist в коде c# для созданного экземпляра объекта?**

В документации описан только такой способ применения свойства:

```
MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.ElevationAssist.SetElevation(exerciseCard, Elevation.Dp0);
```

Но он задает свойство только объекту в xaml.

Comment: Вам не нужно из кода их создавать. Создайте в XAML шаблон `ItemTemplate` и используйте `ListView` с привязкой к данным с использованием `ObservableCollection`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1192928/373567

Comment: @aepot, хорошо, попробую